# "Reset Keyboard Dictionary" not working

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, dictionary, autocorrect

My iPhone is running iOS 7.0.4.  I am trying to use the "Reset Keyboard Dictionary" option because certain text like an "i" in the middle of a sentence no longer auto capitalizes.  Auto capitalization and autocorrect are on.  When I hit Reset Keyboard Dictionary there is no change in behavior.  My i's still don't upper case.  I know I can add new keyboard shortcuts to force things like this but single character corrections don't work well (iOS doesn't know whether they are in a word or a separate word).

If I erase my iPhone completely and set it up as new (as a test), all is good.

Why isn't Reset Keyboard Dictionary working?

Comment: Try resetting your iPhone immediately after resetting keyboard dictionary.

Comment: If by "reset" you mean reboot by holding down power and home, no good.